# How to get review comments from Code Review Response Task in Azure DevOps?

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops

Tried various approaches to extract Code review comments programmatically from Azure DevOps. I can query both tasks (Code Review Request & Code Review Response) but unable to retrieve the comments given by the reviewer.

In TFS, DiscussionThread and IDiscussionManager to get the comments. But it no lon

[image: Code Review Response in VS 2017]

Approach 1:
Tried using GetCommentsAsync() from namespace Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.WebApi

Approach 2:
'content' will be in JSON format. I cannot find any review comments from this also.

```
 internal class Program
    {
        // URI and PERSONALACCESSTOKEN are removed in the sample code due to security reasons.
        // I referred this link for below details https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/pats
        private const string URI = "";
        private const string PERSONALACCESSTOKEN = "";    

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetTaskDetail(85527).Wait();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private static async Task GetTaskDetail(int workItemId)
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", PERSONALACCESSTOKEN))));

                using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(
                            string.Format(URI + "_apis/wit/workitems/{0}?$expand=all&api-version=5.0", workItemId)).Result)
                {
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You should use `await` instead of calling `.Result` on the tasks returned from async methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DiscussionThread and IDiscussionManager with [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient).

Rest Api still does not contain methods to get discussions in a code review.